# passing own data to trading view

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api, datafeed

I was working with trading view(https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NASDAQ:AAPL&source=unauth_header&feature=launch_chart) charting library, It shows the data for the currency pair as intended.

I have looked into the following guideline
[tradingview charting library](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-tutorial)

Now what I am looking for is to plot the chart with my own data. Is there any widget or any way I can provide my own data to tradingview and it will create the candlestick chart with the data provided.

Answer (score 4):

yes you can feed your data with custom DataFeed.

you should set datafeed property of your widgetOptions like this

```
let options={
... other options
datafeed:new UDFCompatibleDatafeed('url api url'),
... other options
}
_chart = new widget(this.options);
```